# How to, Take a text file and wrap every word with a tag <v> </v>

Tags: php

I want to take plain text and wrap every word with an element

like so

```
<v>Archer</v> <v>aŭtomobilis</v> <v>fore</v> <v>de</v> <v>antaŭkristnaska</v> <v>festo</v> <v>en</v> <v>suda</v> <v>apudurbo</v>. <v>Malgraŭ</v>
```

What is the best way to do this in php thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");

while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "<v>$tok</v>";
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
```

Comment: I think you'll replace symbols like `.` as well

Answer (score 3):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to find words and replace them with wrapped version:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\w+)/', '<v>\1</v>', $string);
```

Regular expression works as following:

- `/` is delimeter of regular exprtession, everything between `/.../` is expression itself
- `(...)` - is capturing group which saves result of inner regexp into special array
- `\w` - means word character
- `\w+` - means 1 or more word characters

In replacement `\1` means value of first group saved in regexp.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what '/(\w+)/g' is telling the computer,(?whitespace = (/w+) and /g = what? and I get '<v>\1</v>' but why the 1,  can I wrap every other word in something else?

Comment: \w = any word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)

\w+ = any word character one or more times

(\w+) capture any word character one or more times in a backreference

/(\w+)/g = make the search global on the string

The \1 in the second argument tells preg_replace to put the matched string from (\w+) into <v>here</v>

Comment: @Johrn: `/g` is not listed on the PHP Manual, care to explain what it does in a little more detail?

Comment: I've removed `/g`. It's not needed in PHP.

Comment: didn't realize that PHP didn't need /g. oh well