# how to make a string like " abcde fghijk " into " *abcde* *fghijk* " in php?

Tags: php, string

I have a string eg `abcde fghijk` and am trying to convert it into `*abcdef* *fghijk*`and another thing is that it should work for any value that can be entered in place of `abcde fghijk`

Comment: Those strings are the same?

Comment: how to make a string like " abcde fghijk " into " *abcde* *fghijk* " in php

Comment: As in adding italics?

Comment: actually i have to add * before abcde and after it too

Comment: same for fghijk

Comment: Umm... I'm really confused as to what you are asking. Are your trying to turn " abcde fghijk " into " \*\*abcde\*\* \*\*fghijk\*\* "?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to, Take a text file and wrap every word with a tag <v> </v>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118851/how-to-take-a-text-file-and-wrap-every-word-with-a-tag-v-v)

Comment: exactly Jordan. Only one *

Comment: `preg_replace("/\w+/", "*$0*", " abcde fghijk ")`

Comment: I have a string eg `abcde fghijk` and am trying to convert it into `*abcdef* *fghijk*` and another thing is that it should work for any value that can be entered in place of `abcde fghijk`

Comment: Please review how to write a good question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Following the details on that page by editing this question may help you get the answer you are looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is pretty much what you're expecting:

```
$str = ' abcde fghijk ';
$str = preg_replace('/(\w+)/', '*$1*', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Works on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/94rm-wvwy)

Comment: Though it might take slightly more time than the array_map solution by @Kris Roofe... See the output of [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rr6u-mjgp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = 'abcde fghijk lmnopq';
$array = explode(' ', $string);
$array = array_map(function($v){return "*".$v."*";}, $array);
$string = implode(' ', $array);
var_dump($string);
```

result:

```
kris-roofe@krisroofe-Rev-station:~$ php cal.php 
string(25) "*abcde* *fghijk* *lmnopq*"
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php

```
$value = str_replace("abcde", "*abcde*", " abcde fghijk ");
$value = str_replace("fghijk", "*fghijk*", $value);
```