# how to properly replace hyphen with div elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following text **stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world** by hyphen. I need to replace those hyphen and surround each text within div tags as per result sample below

```
<div class='cssx'>stackoverflow</div>
<div class='cssx'>is</div>
<div class='cssx'>the</div>
<div class='cssx'>best</div>
<div class='cssx'>in</div>
<div class='cssx'>the</div>
<div class='cssx'>world</div>
```

In PHP I can get it working as follow.

```
<?php
$str ="stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world";
echo $output = str_replace('-', "<div class='cssx'></div>", $str);

?>
```

**Here is my issue.** I need to get it working with  **javascript.** To this effect, I have leveraged solution here
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118851/how-to-take-a-text-file-and-wrap-every-word-with-a-tag-v-v)

but cannot get it to work.

**here is the code so far.**

```
const str ="stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world";

var output = "<div class='cssx'>" + 
"text.replace(/-/g, "</div><div class='cssx'>", str)" +
 "</div>";

alert(output);
```

Comment: Use combination of `split()`, `map()` and `join()` to achieve this. It is much more readable and maintainable

Comment: `['<div class="cssx">', 'stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world'.split('-').join('<\/div><div class="cssx">'), '<\/div>'].join('');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only needs a small fix. You should call the replace method on the `str` variable instead of using it as a string. Something like:

```js
const str = "stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world";

const output = "<div class='cssx'>" +
  str.replace(/-/g, "</div><div class='cssx'>") +
  "</div>";

alert(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split()` function to separate the string into an array of words and then use `map()` to create a new array with each word wrapped in `<div>` tags.

```js
let str = "stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world";
let wordsArray = str.split('-');

let output = wordsArray.map(word => `<div class='cssx'>${word}</div>`).join('');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain your style of code, then replace this line:

```js
"text.replace(/-/g, "</div><div class='cssx'>", str)"
```

with

```js
str.replaceAll( "-", "</div><div class='cssx'>" )
```

**Reasons:**

1. You have quotes surrounding the `text.replace(..)` call. This will make the code itself the text.
2. There is no variable named `text`. Hence, replace it with `str`, your actual variable.
3. `replace(..)` will replace only the first instance. You need `replaceAll(..)` for replacing all `-`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below  tag in to your HTML page so it will work same as the above PHP.

```
<script>
var inputText = "stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world";
var words = inputText.split('-');

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    document.write("<div class='cssx'>" + words[i] + "</div>");
}
```

It splits the input text into an array of words using the split method and then iterates through the array, writing each word surrounded by  and  tags to the document

Answer (score 0):

Below javascript code will work perfectly

```js
function convertToDivs(input) {
  const words = input.split('-');
  let output = '';
  for (const word of words) {
    output += `<div class='cssx'>${word}</div>\n`;
  }
  return output;
}

const input = 'stackoverflow-is-the-best-site-in-the-world';
const output = convertToDivs(input);
console.log(output);
```